# How to execute logic if switch value is other than the choices?

Tags: c#

This might be the most simple question of all time but how do you make it so that if I write something that isn't one of  the choices 1,2,3,4 the program will say "Wrong choice, try again" ?

For example: If the user types in "36" the program should say "Wrong choice, try again"

I know I can use if and if else for choice 1,2,3,4 and then use else for it to write "Wrong choice" but is there any shorter/easier way of doing it?

```
using System;

namespace atmtest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int choice;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("1) Example 1");
                Console.WriteLine("2) Example 2");
                Console.WriteLine("3) Example 3");
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Choose one of the 3 options");
                choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose 1");
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose 2");
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose 3");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just set the default in the switch statement, like:

```
switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("You chose 1");
        break;

    case 2:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("You chose 2");
        break;

    case 3:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("You chose 3");
        break;

    default:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong option!");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Solved, tysm :D